# Pandas: what is truth value condition when dealing with missing data

Tags: pandas, missing-data

I have a function that creates a ratio. It is defined as

```
def create_ratio(data,num,den):
    if data[num].isnull():
        ratio = -9997
    if data[den].isnull():
        ratio = -9998
    if data[num].isnull() & data[den].isnull():
        ratio = -9999
    else:
        ratio = data[num]/data[den]
    return ratio
```

I have pandas dataframe (df_credit) which includes credit card balance (cc_bal) and limit (cc_limit) and I want to calculate credit card utilization which is balance over limit

```
df_credit['cc_util'] = create_ratio(df_credit,'cc_bal','cc_limit')
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-d53809a7690d> in <module>
----> 1 data['ratio_cc_util'] = create_ratio(data,'open_credit_card_credit_limit_nomiss','open_credit_card_credit_limit_nomiss')
      2 data['ratio_cc_util'].hist()

<ipython-input-65-99bc55b184ed> in create_ratio(data, num, den)
      1 def create_ratio(data,num,den):
----> 2     if data[num].isnull():
      3         ratio = -9997
      4     if data[den].isnull():
      5         ratio = -9998

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1441     def __nonzero__(self):
   1442         raise ValueError(
-> 1443             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1444             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1445         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is the solution to this error? Thanks.

Comment: you are m mixing scalars and series... `ratio` is sometimes a scalar (-9997, etc) and in else condition a series `data[num]/data[den]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you are mixing between scalars and series, where your function needs to return a series or array given its calling context
- as simple way as any to implement this conditional logic is `np.select()`
- have simulated data,  including missing values to meet your use cases

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "cc_bal": np.random.uniform(200, 1000, 200),
        "cc_limit": np.random.uniform(800, 1200, 200),})

df.loc[np.unique(np.random.choice(range(len(df)), 30)), "cc_bal"] = None
df.loc[np.unique(np.random.choice(range(len(df)), 30)), "cc_limit"] = None


def create_ratio(df, num, den):
    return np.select(
        [
            df[num].isnull() & df[den].isnull(),
            df[num].isnull(),
            df[den].isnull(),
        ],
        [-9999, -9997, -9998],
        df[num] / df[den],
    )


df["ratio"] = create_ratio(df, "cc_bal", "cc_limit")
df
```

#### sample output

|  | cc_bal | cc_limit | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 372.633 | 981.996 | 0.379465 |
| 1 | 845.541 | 1133.69 | 0.745831 |
| 2 | 449.406 | 975.903 | 0.460503 |
| 3 | 209.827 | 922.829 | 0.227374 |
| 4 | 237.347 | 936.654 | 0.253398 |
| 5 | 351.154 | nan | -9998 |
| 6 | nan | 873.671 | -9997 |
| 7 | 803.396 | 861.791 | 0.93224 |
| 8 | 591.136 | 807.176 | 0.732352 |
| 9 | 675.397 | 847.059 | 0.797344 |